# Регулярное выражение находящее идущие подряд одинаковые слова

Tags: c#

> *Дан фрагмент текста на русском языке, запрашиваемый у пользователя. Написать программу, проверяющую, встречаются ли в нём идущие подряд одинаковые слова. Словом считается последовательность букв, содержащая не более, чем один дефис. Слово не может начинаться с дефиса или заканчиваться на него.*

У меня есть один textBox и button. В textBox ввожу слова и проверяю нажав на кнопку.

Используются регулярные выражения.

```
string pattern = @"\b(\w+?)\s\1\b";
string input = textBox1.Text;
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{ 
    // Как сделать проверку с if? Если есть в начале слова дефис и в 
    // конце, то выводить надпись "Слово не может начинаться с дефиса или 
    // заканчиваться на него."
    // иначе
    // MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} ( Повторяется '{1}') позиция {2}", 
    // match.Value, match.Groups[1].Value, match.Index));
}
```

Comment: `if (myword.StartsWith("-") && myword.EndsWith("-")) {...} else {...}` ?

Comment: Не то, если вводишь "слово слово", то идет проверка, что они повторяются, а если "-cлово- слово", то вообще ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что это делается вот так:

```
(?<!-)\b(\w+(?:-\w+)?)(?!-)\s+\1\b
```

Comment: @gregzakharov, на моём знании регулярок :)

Comment: @gregzakharov, можно флаг игнорирования регистра добавить. И можно `\s+` заменить на `\W+`. По поводу русских слов - в вопросе говорится, что весь текст на русском. Не вижу причин искать только русские в произвольном тексте, но если надо, то можно добавить.

Comment: @gregzakharov, при замене `\s+` на `\W+` и указании флага для игнорирования регистра проигнорирует?

Comment: скорее так ```(?i:(?<!-)\b([а-яё]+(-[а-яё]+)?)(?!-)(\W+\1)+\b)```

Comment: @gregzakharov, ты меняешь: 1. `\w` на `[а-яё]` - это поиск русских слов в произвольном тексте. 2. `\s+` на `\W+` - разрешить знаки препинания между словами. 3. Добавляешь возможность повтора более двух раз (кстати должно быть не `\1)+\b`, а `\1\b)+` UPDATE: хотя можно и так, в данном случае). Про первые 2 пункта я говорил, третий для проверки на да/нет не требуется. Ну и `(?i:` лучше выставлять флагом на всю регурярку.

Comment: во-первых, не "ты", а "вы" (на брудершафт не пили, чай), во-вторых, мне то зачем разжевывать относительно регулярок?! Я в курсе как они работают, просто на данный момент усталость сказывается. Лучше объясняйте сие автору темы.